# SAT solver optimizations of DPLL for unsatisfiable formulas

Tags: algorithms, logic, satisfiability, sat-solvers

I am implementing a SAT solver based on DPLL algorithm, and it works fine on small formulas and larger satisfiable problems. My case split is based on a tree like structure, where every branch is tried one by one until solution for the problem is found or until every branch is tried.

So my problem now is that the above described approach does not terminate when trying to find a solution on large UN-SAT problems (so there shouldn't be a solution), therefore my program tries every possibility $2^n$, giving it a run time of years to solve UN-SAT problem with $50$+ variables (it would eventually terminate in years as I am not having any memory issues etc.).

My question is: what topics/implementations would I want to look at to speed up the tree processing or this case split process on unsatisfiable problems. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  What research have you done?  There's *lots* written on how modern SAT solvers work and what are the core techniques that make a big difference.  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, to help us help you, and because there's no point in us repeating material that's already widely available in standard resources (websites, Wikipedia) or through a simple web search.

Comment: In this case, if you read the Wikipedia articles on [the DPLL algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm#Current_work) and on [Boolean satisfiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Algorithms_for_solving_SAT), they describe the main techniques: [conflict analysis and clause learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-Driven_Clause_Learning), [non-chronological backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backjumping), and two-watched-literals unit propagation.  I suggest you go read about those and try implementing them.  They should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Conflict analysis and clause learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-Driven_Clause_Learning) and [non-chronological backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backjumping) should help a lot, for both satisfiable and unsatisfiable instances.  They discover large portions of the search space where no solution can reside and prune the search to avoid traversing those.

You could also try two-watched-literals unit propagation, but I'd try the others first, as I expect they'll make a bigger difference.